# how to decode base 64 image and store it to documents directory in iOS in Cordova?

Tags: ios, file, cordova

I am getting a base 64 string of a image and i have decoded the to image using the following method:

```
var file = 'data:image/png;base64;charset=UTF-8,'+base64String;
```

I would like to store this file to document directory in iOS. Can any one suggest me an idea to do the same. I have searched a lot for a solution.

Comment: Have you tried using the File plugin?

Comment: yes. but here in my case i have file in js file. Using file plugin we can copy from one folder to another. and also there is option to write a text to text file.

Comment: Not sure if this worked, but you may find it helpful toward a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404805/how-to-persists-file-in-iphone-with-phonegap-by-base-64-encoded-string?rq=1

Comment: I have solved it by creating a new plugin for ios. Thanks for your comments